# API key in Simperium for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, simperium

I have 2 API keys in a Simperium app: APIKey1 and APIKey2.
I access Simperium with User1 and APIKey1 and I change some data.
Later I access Simperium agai but this time with User2 and APIKey2 and again, I change some more data in the app.

At this point will changes be visible to both User1 and User2 or the different API keys provide a sort of isolation for the data so that users using APIKey1 can see only data changed with APIKey1? 
Or will different API keys access the same data anyway (no isolation...everybody can see data of everybody else) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is stored per App ID, for a given User. Meaning that User 1 should have access to the same data, no matter if you're using APIKey1 or APIKey2.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. So that means User1 cannot see data of User2 even if they are in the same app Am I right?

Comment: Thad' be right Sergio. Data isn't shared among different users (unless you explicitly use the Collaboration API: https://www.simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#objectshare)

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed to know. You are fantastic Jorge!

Comment: Happy to help Sergio! if anything, please, feel free to open a github issue directly in the Simperium's repository. Have an awesome day!